# Rails Model Relationships for Rugby Players

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, database-design, rails-activerecord

I have two models in my rails 4.2.4 project that I'd like to join together and I'm struggling with creating the correct relationship between the two.
The domain in question is rugby and the code is all available at https://github.com/rgbycch/rgbycch-rest/tree/rails. The models are:

`Player` (https://github.com/rgbycch/rgbycch-rest/blob/rails/app/models/player.rb)
`PlayerPosition` (https://github.com/rgbycch/rgbycch-rest/blob/rails/app/models/player_position.rb)

I'd like to be able to create a relationship whereby a `Player` can have multiple favoured `PlayingPosition`s. I believe my db structure would need to look something like this:

```
create_table :favoured_positions do |t|
  t.references :player, index: true, foreign_key: true # fk to player table
  t.references :player_position, index: true, foreign_key: true # fk to player_position table
  t.integer :num_favs # additional data for a favored playing position

  t.timestamps null: false
end
```

I can generate a new `FavoredPosition` model like this I guess:

```
bundle exec bin/rails generate model FavouredPosition player:references player_position:references num_favs:integer
```

which generates a class that looks like:

```
class FavouredPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :player
  belongs_to :player_position
end
```

I'm not sure how to alter my `Player` and `PlayerPosition` models to reflect this new relationship. Is the following correct:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favored_positions, :through => :favoured_positions
end

class PlayerPositions < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favored_playing_positions, :through => :favoured_positions
end
```

Would you advise me to add indexes to either of these tables too?

Thanks,

Sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to set up the associations like this:

```
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favoured_positions
  has_many :player_positions, through: :favoured_positions
end

class PlayerPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :favoured_positions
  has_many :players, through: :favoured_positions
end
```

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: Thanks for the answer @EgonWilzer.

Answer (score 1):

**Firstly**, change `PlayerPosition` to `Position`, it's far simpler and works with the [DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

**Secondly**, what you're referring to is an [ActiveRecord association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-types-of-associations). These are basically how the ActiveRecord ORM allows you to associate objects in Rails.

--

[**`has_many :through`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/images/has_many_through.png)

[image]

The association I feel you'd best using is either going to be [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) or [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association). Since you've comitted to `has_many :through`, here's what you need to do:

```
#app/models/player.rb
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
    #columns id | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
    has_many :favoured_positions
    has_many :positions, through: :favoured_positions
end

#app/models/position.rb
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | etc | etc | created_at | updated_at
   has_many :favoured_positions
   has_many :players, through: :favoured_positions
end

#app/models/favoured_position.rb
class FavouredPosition < ActiveRecord::Base
   #columns id | position_id | player_id | any | other | column | created_at | updated_at
   belongs_to :position
   belongs_to :player
end
```

--

[**`has_and_belongs_to_many`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/images/habtm.png)

[image]

An important caveat about the difference between `has_many :through` and `has_and_belongs_to_many`. If you *didn't* have any extra columns in your `favoured_positions` join model, I would recommend you use `has_and_belongs_to_many`. It's far simpler for what you need:

```
#app/models/player.rb
class Player < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :positions
end

#app/models/position.rb
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :players
end
```

You'd then make a join table as follows:

```
#players_positions
player_id | position_id
```